# Android: Facebook SDK make a post with location on the bottom

Tags: android, facebook, post, sdk, location

I'm trying to integrate posting to the users wall from within my app using the Facebook SDK. Simple Posting is no Problem but I'm trying to add the Location (on the Bottom of the Post behind the time) where the user actually is.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This is simple, whenever you are making the Graph API POST call to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed` you should include a parameter `place` with a value of a Page ID associated with a Place. This is shown in the [Graph API User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) documentation.

You can use [Graph API search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) to locate any Page IDs near to a specified location by using a Graph API call like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000`

Where `center` is the latitude and longitude and `distance` restricts how far away the place can be from that center.

Comment: Well thats true but this results in linking a place to the post. But i would prefer to add the location under the post ("... posted 1 hour ago near town")

Comment: I believe that is your only option if you are just making a /feed publish call. There are other options for Open Graph actions.